# SQL alchemy ORM bracketing And statements with OR statements

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm wondering if someone can help me convert this SQL query to SQL alchemy ORM. I am having issues in bracketing the And statements with Or statements. Here is a simpler version of the query I am trying to create:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[UpcomingThings] WHERE ([Id] = 'ES1234' AND [Date] = '2021-08-18' AND [Period] = 27) OR ([Id] = 'ES0197' AND [Date] = '2021-08-18' AND [Period] = 29)
```

Note that Id in this case is not unique, so I have to rely on multiple other columns to make it unique. I have tried using .filter and .filter(_or()) in various combinations but I cant seem to get it so that its a WHERE (bracket and condition) OR (bracket and condition)

EDIT:
if sql alchemy was as simple as this, this is what i'd do assuming _or would give me an OR:

```
session.query(models.UpcomingThings).filter(UpcomingThings.Id == 'ES1234').filter(UpcomingThings.Period == 27).filter(UpcomingThings.SettlementDate == 2021-08-18).filter(or_(UpcomingThings.Id=='ES0197')).filter(UpcomingThings.Date == 2021-08-18)).filter(UpcomingThings.Period == 29))
```

Is there also no way I could do

```
session.query(models.UpcomingThings).filter(or_((AND STATEMENT), (AND STATEMENT))
```

I've tried to simply even do a .filter inside the or_ but obviously thats a syntax error!

Please can someone help convert this to SQLalchemy ORM! Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what isn't working? Please add something minimal and point out what fails!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will seem clear after the fact but you need to use `and_` and `or_` to achieve this.  The call to `filter()` applies an implicit `and_` but it won't work when you need the outer sql `OR`.  This should do what you want to achieve.  I tried to format it to make it more clear.  `or_` will join the conditions with sql `OR` and `and_` will join the conditions with `AND`.

In one case you use `SettlementDate` and another just `Date`, should those be the same?  I just changed it to `SettlementDate` to try the schema.

## Python Example

```py
#...
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_, and_
from datetime import date

class UpcomingThings(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'upcoming_things'
   Id = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
   Period = Column(Integer)
   SettlementDate = Column(Date)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    q = session.query(
       UpcomingThings
    ).filter(
       or_(
          and_(
             UpcomingThings.Id=='ES1234',
             UpcomingThings.Period==27,
             UpcomingThings.SettlementDate==date(year=2021, month=8, day=18)),
          and_(
             UpcomingThings.Id=='ES0197',
             UpcomingThings.SettlementDate==date(year=2021, month=8, day=18),
             UpcomingThings.Period==29)))
    print (q)
```

## Printed Output

```
SELECT upcoming_things."Id" AS "upcoming_things_Id", upcoming_things."Period" AS "upcoming_things_Period", upcoming_things."SettlementDate" AS "upcoming_things_SettlementDate" 
FROM upcoming_things 
WHERE upcoming_things."Id" = ? AND upcoming_things."Period" = ? AND upcoming_things."SettlementDate" = ? OR upcoming_things."Id" = ? AND upcoming_things."SettlementDate" = ? AND upcoming_things."Period" = ?
```

Comment: This answer is perfect thank you so much. There's not really proper documentation on using ands in conjunction with ors but now I feel dumb for not trying to use the parenthesis in this way! So far I've gotten around it with using union and subqueries but this is far simpler and I suspect will lead to better performance as I will be passing in alot more parameters.